# CodeIgniter migration from 1.7.2 to 2.0 returns blank page

Tags: php, codeigniter, migration

I have the task to migrate a codeigniter webpage from 1.7.2 to 2.0 ( 2.2 ) and then I need to migrate it to 3.0. 
I followed [this guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_200.html).

After I did everything I uploaded it to the ftp and now I am getting a blank page.

I think I've got all things done as by the tutorial but even if I have missed something I at least need an indication for that. But I am getting nothing but a blank page.

I enabled `error_reporting` - nothing.

Configured the `log_threshhold` to 1, and again - nothing.

Comment: check your default controller did you set ?

Comment: Yes. The default controller is set to a controller extending MY_Controller, which extends CI_Controller. Of course I've put MY_Controller.php in the core folder, as said in the guide.

Comment: i mean did you set `$route['default_controller'] = "";` ? in config/routes

Comment: yes it's set and everything else is commented so it doesn't get in the way.

Comment: make sure php5-mysql is installed.

Comment: yep it is. I wrote phpinfo() in the index.php in the main directory just above error_reporting and it's running. it says PHP Version 5.4.10 and all the usual stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you got error 500 or something, so make your error reporting (not only on codeigniter)  on on your web server or htacces file by adding

```
php_flag display_errors on
```

and check your php error log if is available for you.